# Trying to pass a function back to App.js and getting stuck REACT

Tags: html, reactjs, components, jsx

I have an app that allows me to add a list of clients by input. I also have a another component that allows me to choose one of the existing clients from a dropdown menu and create a 'new lesson' with them. This way I can log my lessons done with my clients. This all works perfectly... this is where I get stuck.

Everytime I add a new lesson, I want to take the duration of the lesson (in hours) and multiply that by the corresponding client's price. I then want to be able to display that profit and everytime I add a new lesson with a new profit, I want it all to add up to a totalProfit of all the lessons.

This is App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Clients from './components/Clients'
import AddClient from './components/AddClient'
import NavBar from './components/NavBar'
import AddLesson from './components/AddLesson'
import CalculateIncome from './components/CalculateIncome'

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    clients : [
      // {id : null , name : '', price : null}
    ],
    lessons : [
      // {id: null, name: '', time: null, date :null}
    ],
  }

  deleteClient = (id) => {
    let clients = this.state.clients.filter(client => {
      return client.id !== id
    })
    this.setState({
      clients: clients
    })
  }

  addClient = (newClient) => {
    newClient.id = Math.random();
    let clients = [...this.state.clients, newClient];
    clients.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
    this.setState({
        clients: clients,
    })
  }

  addLesson = (newLesson) => {
    newLesson.id = Math.random();
    newLesson.date = Date();
    let lessons = [...this.state.lessons, newLesson];
    this.setState({
        lessons: lessons,
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <NavBar/>
        <Clients clients={this.state.clients} deleteClient={this.deleteClient} lessons={this.state.lessons}/>
        <AddClient addClient={this.addClient}/>
        <AddLesson addLesson={this.addLesson} lessons={this.state.lessons} clients={this.state.clients} income={this.state.income} />
        <CalculateIncome lessons={this.state.lessons} clients={this.state.clients}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is CalculateIncome.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class CalculateIncome extends Component {
        state = {
            totalIncome:0
        }

        calculation = () => {
            this.props.lessons.filter(lesson => {
                this.props.clients.filter(client => {
                    if (client.name === lesson.name){
                        let price = client.price
                        let time = lesson.time
                        return(price, time)
                    }
                    return (
                        this.setState({
                            totalIncome : (price * time)
                        })
                    )
                })       
            })
        }

        render() {
            return ( this.props.lessons.length ? 
            (this.state.totalIncome)  
                : 
            (<div className="text-center my-5">You are broke</div>) 
        )
    }
}

export default CalculateIncome
```

If you need to see any other components including AddLesson.js and Clients.js please let me know I will post it up as well.

Comment: Excuse me but what exactly is your question ?

Comment: I have some components: App.js, Clients.js, AddClient.js AddLesson.js, and CalculateIncome.js. I am able to add clients and use those existing clients to add a lesson corresponding to each client. Each lesson has a time duration and each client has a price per hour. I want to create a function that will multiply (lesson.time * client.price) so I can know my income. My question is where would I put this function, would I put it straight in App.js or in AddLesson.js or would it just be its own calculation in CalculateIncome.js and how would I pass these properties up and down the components?